# How to change CSS element of data-pid using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an array of instances defined by a `data-pid` eg. `data-pid="0", data-pid="1", etc...`

I'm trying to have the background image of a container change when each instance is clicked.

Here's the code I'm working with, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
$( "div[data-pid='0']" ).one( "click", function() {
  $( "#primary .bcg" ).css( "background", "url(folder/path)" );
});
```

If I change the the code to a specific element on the page, for instance `#primary` instead of div`[data-pid='0']` it works fine.

Anyone know how to overcome this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `.one` to `.on` and your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/1ro7hhef/

Comment: Thanks @JonP That looks like it will work

Comment: @EricBrockman [this is a simple typo](http://jsfiddle.net/33embjhj/1/) please check your syntax properly before asking for advice here. Voting to close. (FYI, the typo in your question is the "e" added to "on", and the typo in your fiddle is missing a quote " in your selector - the syntax highlighting clearly shows this in JSFiddle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **one** event handler so that your click event get fired only for first time.

Try this:

```
$("div[data-pid='0']").on( "click", function() {
   $( "#primary .bcg" ).css( "background", "url(folder/path)" );
});
```